# Unable to target child element of Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Here is my code

```
    javascript: (function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("app-view").children[1];
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.open(img);
    })();
```

and [here is the app element](https://clippingmagic.com/images/10580558/edit/pmbg4ec40ij05dlca3aect7luepe7bbjcgashkcr926vge3a07um) where I wish to target the second canvas element "children[1](https://clippingmagic.com/images/10580558/edit/pmbg4ec40ij05dlca3aect7luepe7bbjcgashkcr926vge3a07um)" but it's not working for some reason and always gets stuck at the first element. A solution will be much appreciated, thanks in advance! 
[image]

In the picture it always targets the first canvas in yellow but I need the one displayed in blue. You can test the code by saving the script as a bookmark in your browser.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from giving each canvas an ID, and selecting them directly?

Comment: @TiesonT. the site is not mine so can't really do anything from the inside

Comment: I see, I used console to log the canvas, and it seems to definitely be selecting the right canvas, but it's still getting the image data of the left canvas. Strange, even if you add an id to the canvas, and use getElementById, it still shows the left canvas. So now the question becomes, why is toDataURL giving the image data of the left canvas, even when you definitely use it on the right canvas

Comment: @GregHornby yeah ! Previously the right side image used to show options on right clicking but those options are now gone and only shows up for the left image. Maybe some script is manipulating it

Comment: The only thing I can think of is both canvases share the same content, and the white background trick is just an overlay of another element

Comment: hmm looks like a tricky one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't worked out why toDataURL gets the data of the left canvas, but if you wanted to save the canvas, you can isolate it with

```
var can = document.getElementById("app-view").children[1];
jQuery("body > *").remove();
jQuery("body").append(can) ;
```

and then now you can right click and save the canvas

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
document.getElementById('app-view').childNodes[1]
```

Comment: still not working ! It always ends up targeting the first canvas